# Entity Framework 6 SaveChanges extremandamente lento

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net, entity-framework-6

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion en WPF, y utilizo Entity Framework v6.1.3 como ORM, base de datos sql server 2012 como base de datos.

La consulta es simple. Hacer un insert de 8 mil registros aproximadamente, me demora mas de 15 minutos. Lo que demora realmente esa cantidad de tiempo es cuando ejecuta el SaveChanges.

Mi clase repositorio es la siguiente.

```
public class RelevamientosRepository:ABMRepository
    {
        public void AddModels(List<Relevamiento> relevamientos)
        {
            using (EnsayosContext _context = new EnsayosContext())
            {
                _context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

                foreach (Relevamiento relevamiento in relevamientos)
                {           
                    relevamiento.TipoRelevamiento = null;
                    relevamiento.Parcela = null;
                    _context.Entry(relevamiento).State = (relevamiento.EsNuevo) ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
                }

                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

A su vez en el context tengo un override del savechanges, para guardar fecha y hora de inser o modificacion.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            foreach (var history in this.ChangeTracker.Entries()
                .Where(e => e.Entity is IModificationHistory && (e.State== EntityState.Added || e.State== EntityState.Modified))
                .Select(e => e.Entity as IModificationHistory))
            {
                history.DateModified = DateTime.Now;
                if (history.DateCreated == DateTime.MinValue)
                {
                    history.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
                }
            }

            int result = base.SaveChanges();

            return result;
        }
```

**¿Cómo hacer para optimizar el grabado de datos?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede ser que el override de SaveChanges esté haciendo demasiado trabajo. Podrías usar una alternativa. Triggers en SQL Server por ejemplo. Pero lo que sí es verdad que para bulk operations EF no es un buen camino.

Con SqlBulkCopy hice inserts parecidos de 10000 registros y 30 campos, y no llevaba más de unos segundos en completar la operación, también es una buena alternativa y será MUY rápida en comparación de EF.

Podrías intentar convertir esa `List<Relevamiento>` a DataTable ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253725/convert-ienumerable-to-datatable))
Y luego usar el SqlBulkCopy para enviar esa información a la tabla destino. Te va a ahorrar mucho tiempo ya que todo se hace en memoria.

Comment: SqlBulkCopy  es una libreria paga verdad?

Comment: No, sólo debes usar using System.Data.SqlClient;

Comment: var dataTable = new DataTable();//este sería tu datatable  
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection("tuConnectionString"))  
    using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))  
            {  
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);  
            }

Comment: Aquí un ejemplo que te puede ayudar [SQL Bulk Copy](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16922/SQL-Bulk-Copy-with-C-Net)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar desactivar algunas validaciones como `context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;` o `context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;`

De todas maneras, EF es lento por naturaleza para las "BulkOperations". Yo te recomendaría, si tienes que actualizar un nº elevado de registros, que usaras por ejemplo [SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx).
También existen clases externas para EF que tratan de solucionar esto, por ejemplo las [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)